# Use old pc & Ubuntu to stream video to TV

Tags: stream

Sorry if this has been covered elsewhere.  Perhaps I lack the terminology  to find the solution.

I have an old PC (Acer Aspire e1-470p)  which I have wiped and installed Ubuntu 18.10.   I’d like to use it as a media server.

I have an older (dumb) tv with a Roku box. I also have a 2TB HDD attached by USB3 to my Linksys 1900AC

I’ve noticed that some apps / clients in my roku don’t find some file formats on the HDD which VLC and other apps can play.

I’d like to use an app on the Ubuntu box to (perhaps store and) stream video formats to my Roku box. 
What Unix based apps have the best ability to decode and stream all video formats do thin roku apps like Plex etc?

Or if I’m decoding the video on the server, does that imply that I’m really just trying to mirror the screen To the Tv? (Confuses)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a plenty of answers to your question. But please let me recommend you to use Kodi., A mediacenter, that is build to get the files from different source, put it in a database and access them easy. Perfect for a home media center ... As said before, it is not the only way to solve your question, but one of the easier ones, also because it is shipped with ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/kodi

Comment: Thanks.  I will research Kodi, but can it decode MKV to stream to Roku? Or are you suggesting I use PC replace Roku?

Comment: I thought the roku is the storage in another room. If you'd want the system as a storage with transcoding, I'm out. ... I've played around with PS3 Media Server (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS3_Media_Server) ... This should be a good start, if you know what protocol is your Roku using.

Comment: Emby server is also a good alternative.